# Integrate a fraction...

Tags: integration, derivatives

How do I integrate this fraction: $$\dfrac{x+\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt[3]{x}}$$ I appreciate your help, I only need a solution for this example, the rest I'll do alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT : $$\frac{x+\sqrt{x}}{x^{1/3}}=\frac{x^1}{x^{1/3}}+\frac{x^{1/2}}{x^{1/3}}=x^{1-(1/3)}+x^{(1/2)-(1/3)}=x^{2/3}+x^{1/6}.$$
Then, you can use
$$\int x^\alpha dx=\frac{x^{\alpha+1}}{\alpha+1}+C\ \ \ \ \ (\alpha\not=-1).$$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

$$\frac {a+b} c=\frac a c+\frac b c$$

and
$$\int x^p dx=\frac1{p+1} x^{p+1}+C\qquad p\ne-1$$

Comment: Nice to see you my bro. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $x^6=t$ and change the integrand accordingly.